# How to turn off Microsoft Logs in AspNetCore 2.2 NLog

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog

The following is my Logs

> [2019-05-07 15:55:38.4270][PC-20170829ROEW][Info] my logs recorded
>
> [2019-05-07 15:55:38.4929][PC-20170829ROEW][Info] Route matched with {action = >"Get", controller = "Values"}. Executing action >QunarFlight.Web.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (QunarFlight.Web)
>
> [2019-05-07 15:55:38.5798][PC-20170829ROEW][Info] Executing action method >QunarFlight.Web.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (QunarFlight.Web) - Validation >state: Valid
>
> [2019-05-07 15:55:38.6066][PC-20170829ROEW][Info] Executed action method >QunarFlight.Web.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (QunarFlight.Web), returned >result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult in 22.6363ms.
>
> [2019-05-07 15:55:38.6066][PC-20170829ROEW][Info] Executing ObjectResult, >writing value of type 'System.String[]'.

I want to close all Microsoft default logs( Last four records ), only keep the logs I have recorded( the first one record).
i modify appsettings.json on the following

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Warning"
 }
```

in this case, my recorded logs will not be output. if i remove "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Warning" my recorded logs will be output .How should I modify it?

appsettings.json

```
"Logging": {
   "LogLevel": {
     "Default": "Information",
     "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Warning",
     "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "Warning",
     "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Warning"
}
```

configure in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        env.ConfigureNLog("NLog.config");
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
        app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Program.cs

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsetting.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
             .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builderContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
             ;
        })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: Please post your call to the logger and injection of the logger. Do you inject `ILogger` or `ILogger<SomeClass>`?

Comment: Would be a lot easier if you included `${logger}` in your File-Layout in the NLog.config.

Comment: Instead of calling `AddNLog()` and `ConfigureNLog` in `Startup.cs`. Then call `UseNLog()` in `CreateWebHostBuilder`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#4-update-programcs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had included `${logger}` in your file-Layout in NLog.config, then it would be much easier to help you setup the logger-filter.

But I found this random  clue on google:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor:Information: Executing ObjectResult
```

So I guess you need to change your MEL-Config to this:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Infrastructure": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Warning"
 }
```

One could even consider doing it like this:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
 }
```

Notice [NLog v5](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#nlogextensionslogging-without-any-filter) excludes itself from Microsoft LoggerFactory filtering. Instead one can use `finalMinLevel=` in NLog.config (Can also be configured in [appsettings.json](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json)):

```xml
<nlog throwConfigExceptions="true">
    <targets>
       <target name="logTarget" xsi:type="..." />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="System.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
      <logger name="Microsoft.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
      <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime*" finalMinLevel="Info" />
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Debug" writeTo="logTarget" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: i follow your example and add "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning" .

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem because I wanted to set log level for my application logs at Info while logs by Microsoft to be at Warning level.
I realized that Nlog.config overrides the appsettings.json properties.

Also , the order in which you mention the logger names and their restriction matters.

For example , I did

```
 <rules>  
     <logger name="MyClass.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="applogs" />
     <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="applogs" /> 
</rules>
```